# Unable to call method in Adapter from ViewHolder (RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete an item from my RecyclerView when the user clicks on it. However, even though the delete method in the Adapter is public I get the error 'Cannot resolve method delete(int)' when trying to call 'delete' method from the onClick in MyViewHolder.

What gives? It's public so why can't I call it?

GroceryItemAdapter

```
public class GroceryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    List<MetaData> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public GroceryItemAdapter(Context context, List<MetaData> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grocery_item_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        Log.i("GroceryHero", "onCreateViewHolder called");

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MetaData current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconid);
        Log.i("GroceryHero","onBindViewHolder called " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

MyViewHolder:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView title;
ImageView icon;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    Log.i("GroceryHero", "MyViewHolder called");
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grocery_text);
    icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grocery_icon);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item clicked at " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    delete(getAdapterPosition()); // ERROR: Cannot resolve method 
}
}
```

Comment: Your MyViewHolder is innerclass of recyclerview right?

Comment: Move your MyViewHolder class into inner class of the GroceryItemAdapter

Comment: Thanks Sam! Moving the class did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to call `delete` from the view holder class. But `delete` is a method of the adapter class. You can may be pass an instance of adapter to the view holder in `onCreateViewHolder` and store it as a private field.

```
GroceryItemAdapter mAdapter;
public MyViewHolder(View itemView, GroceryItemAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    ...
}

// now you can call
mAdapter.delete(getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: That did it thanks Amarghosh! I passed an instance of the adapter to the view holder with 'MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view, this);' and then could use mAdapter.delete to complete the delete operation. Kudos!

Comment: @Xarsiss Samuel's suggestion would work as well. You can access a class's members from its inner class. So if you don't mind making view holder an inner class of adapter, that should work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Amarghosh and Samuel. I had not moved it as it's inner class which also solves it. I'm glad I can see both solutions.

Comment: hi, is it good practice to pass an adapter to the viewholder ? @Amarghosh

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Can't think of any issues; other option is to declare view holder as inner class, which creates an implicit reference anyway.

Comment: so in the case of an inner class with ViewHolder as a static class, then how do we access a method in the adapter without setting the method to static ? @Amarghosh

Comment: If view holder is a static inner class, it cannot access adapter's methods.  It must be a non-static inner class.